# How to make the content responsive on large screen?

Tags: css

My laptop screen is 1920 x 1080, and it's 15". I have a monitor connected connected to it, that is also 1920 x 1080, but it's much bigger (I think it's 27"). The thing is that I made a website, and it looks good on my laptop's monitor, but when I take it to the big one, it just looks empty... And the text is to small.

I tried using `@media screen and (max-width: 1920px)`, but then it changes so it doesn't look good on my laptop screen.

Is there any way to make the website responsive, but based on the screen size, not the resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for bigger then `1920` screen you have to use `min` instead of `max`.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1920px){}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. It was exactly what I was looking for. I don't know how I didn't think of that. Thank you!